# Facebook Messenger Bot Generic Template redirects to 'Watch' section

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-chatbot

Recently I have noticed that the facebook video links that I pass on a generic template aka "cards" are redirecting the users to "[watch](https://web.facebook.com/watch)" section of facebook.

-I know for sure that this is not an issue with the code but it must be something on facebook end?!

Is anyone experiencing this ?

To satisfy the "need to see some code" requests:

**I'm using [BootBot](https://github.com/Charca/bootbot) and this is my specific implementation:**

```
    const showLatestVideos = (payload, chat) => {
  chat.say({
        cards: [
            { title: '', image_url: 'https://scontent.fprn1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/p370x247/52063931_808166469575942_2311605833122709504_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_ht=scontent.fprn1-1.fna&oh=fa00211a8bdf83959a23bac5971a19f8&oe=5CEE1050', default_action: {
                type: "web_url",
                url: "https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/795477234150322/",
                webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                },
                buttons:[
                  {
                    type:"web_url",
                    url:"https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/795477234150322/",
                    title:"Tagga någon",
                    webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                  }              
                ]
            }, 
            { title: '', image_url: 'https://scontent.fprn1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/p370x247/52171349_1186996514800023_9059384507546730496_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&_nc_ht=scontent.fprn1-1.fna&oh=b9ca303276cbbeb131d5c659b2812e54&oe=5CE89DDB', default_action: {
                type: "web_url",
                url: "https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/241869170093762/",
                webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                },
                buttons:[
                  {
                    type:"web_url",
                    url:"https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/241869170093762/",
                    title:"Berätta",
                    webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                  }              
                ]
            }, 
          { title: 'The most interesting and satisfying video you\'ll ever watch...', image_url: 'https://scontent.fprx1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.5256-10/48349980_984643338399874_7749589283798777856_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ht=scontent.fprx1-1.fna&oh=d4b8f45f9115d561f66e519ec3cad053&oe=5D1DA1BB', default_action: {
        type: "web_url",
                url: "https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/1021393401391534/",
                webview_height_ratio: "tall"
        },
        buttons:[
              {
                type:"web_url",
                url:"https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/1021393401391534/",
                title:"Kommentar",
                webview_height_ratio: "tall"
              }              
            ]
          },
            { title: 'Hur jag lämnande jobbet idga...', image_url: 'https://scontent.fprn1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t15.13418-10/p235x350/52142869_152469279005397_1516129000290779136_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&_nc_ht=scontent.fprn1-1.fna&oh=0aed9824d288ce94f4ed426421c2d910&oe=5D282FFA', default_action: {
                type: "web_url",
                url: "https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/816827101985067/",
                webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                },
                buttons:[
                  {
                    type:"web_url",
                    url:"https://web.facebook.com/SwedenViral/videos/816827101985067/",
                    title:"Tagga någon",
                    webview_height_ratio: "tall"
                  }              
                ]
      }   
        ]
    });
};
```

And this is how the above content/message is sent:

```
bot.hear(['latest', 'videos', 'rate', 'senaste', 'videon'], showLatestVideos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question/issue...

It turned out to be a Facebook bug which is fixed now! Hooray